# Multiple sums from same table

Tags: sql

I'm not even sure if SUM is the correct function to use. Here is what my users view looks like, which joins the users with the points and gets their team name from the team table based on the team ID:

```
Person  TeamName    Points
10      Team A          500
20      A-Team           20
30      Party People    100 
40      Test!           150
50      WhooHoo         200
60      Party People    750
70      Test!            14
```

As you can see, there are two People with the same teamname and I want to display the results as follows grouped by the team:

```
TeamName        Points
Team A          500
A-Team           20
Party People    850
Test!           164
WhooHoo         200
```

Maybe I need to start fresh... here is what I have to work with:

```
Users           teams
user-id         team-id
name            teamName
points
teamid
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select teamName, sum(Points) from users, teams 
on user.team-id = team.team-id
group by teamName
```